# Создать ветку в репозиториию

Tags: git, github

Я форкнулся от репозитория через github. Затем склонил его через консоль, потом также из консоли установил upstream на репозиторий от которого форкнулся. Далее я создал ветку сделал изменения и хочу сделать пул реквест в мой репозиторий. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: `git push -u origin <имя вашей ветки>`

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло это:

```
git push origin <имя вашей ветки>
```